# How to use $(OutDir) with YUICompressor.targets?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, msbuild, appharbor, yui-compressor

I have YUICompressor.NET, http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/, configured as an msbuild task and it is working as expected on my development machine.

When I push the code to AppHarbor then I get the following build error:

```
D:\temp\q2hapsex.50d\input\Projects\CroquetScores.Web\Build\YUICompressor.targets(21,9):
error MSB4062: The "CompressorTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly
D:\temp\q2hapsex.50d\input\Projects\CroquetScores.Web\Build\..\Bin\Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.MsBuildTask.dll.
Could not load file or assembly
'file:///D:\temp\q2hapsex.50d\input\Projects\CroquetScores.Web\Bin\Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.MsbuildTask.dll' 
or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 
Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its
dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements
Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask
```

I have tried the advise at http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/3629-yuicompresoor-msbuild-task by changing the using task in YUICompressor.targets from:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="CompressorTask" AssemblyFile="..\Bin\Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.MsBuildTask.dll" />
```

to

```
<UsingTask TaskName="CompressorTask" AssemblyFile="$(OutDir)Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.MsBuildTask.dll" />
```

I use the following command to test the setup on local machine:

```
msbuild AppHarbor.sln /property:Configuration=Release /property:OutDir=D:\temp\TestingAppHarbor\
```

but it results in the same error except for path information:

```
D:\Code\croquetscores.com\Projects\CroquetScores.Web\Build\YUICompressor.targets(21,9): 
error MSB4062: The "CompressorTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly
D:\Code\croquetscores.com\Projects\CroquetScores.Web\Build\Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.MsBuildTask.dll. 
Could not load file or assembly
'file:///D:\Code\croquetscores.com\Projects\CroquetScores.Web\Build\Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.MsBuildTask.dll'
or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 
Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its
dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements
Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
```

If I replace $(OutDir) in YUICompressor.targets with actual path then the solution builds without error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: These build and path related errors are tricky.. I hope some can help you out. I have been using Cassette for asset handling and at least that one worked like a charm with AppHarbor.

Comment: Can you verify that the `Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.MsBuildTask.dll` assembly is in the output directory at the time msbuild executes the task?

Comment: Yes the file is there when task is executed.

Comment: Please also see the relevant discussion on the AppHarbor support forums: http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/5404-how-to-use-outdir-with-yuicompressortargets

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to use [property functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440.aspx).

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <YuiCompressorDir>$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\Bin'))</YuiCompressorDir>
</PropertyGroup>
<UsingTask TaskName="CompressorTask" AssemblyFile="$(YuiCompressorDir)\Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.MsBuildTask.dll" />
```

You can take a look at *live* [example](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/1ccfcdfc11da#tools/WebStack.settings.targets) from [ASP.NET Web Stack](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/) project.